# Migrate existing Postgres table with foreign key references to declarative partitioning

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I want to apply declarative partitioning to a Postgres table referenced by many other tables with foreign key constraints.

As far as I can tell, Postgres provides limited support for this. The entire procedure seems to be:

1. Rename the target table to `target_old`
2. Create a new partitioned table, `CREATE TABLE target (...) PARTITION BY RANGE (tenant_id)`.
3. Create the partitions.
4. Remove all foreign key references to the original target, which is now named `target_old`.
5. Move data from `target_old` into partitions.
6. Re-add all foreign key references to point to the new `target` table.
7. Copy any important row-level triggers from `target_old` to `target` so they're inherited by the partitions.

Is there a better way?

#### Demo

The following demo creates `tmp.invoice` and `tmp.invoice_state` and attempts to partition `tmp.invoice`.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS tmp;

CREATE TABLE tmp.invoice (
  tenant_id   bigint,
  invoice_id  bigint,
  total_cents bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (tenant_id, invoice_id)
);

-- Generate 30 invoices with 5 tenants.
INSERT INTO tmp.invoice (tenant_id, invoice_id, total_cents)
SELECT t % 5 AS tenant_id, t AS invoice_id, t AS total_cents
FROM generate_series(0, 29) t;


-- Create invoice states so there's a foreign key constraint on tmp.invoice.
CREATE TABLE tmp.invoice_state (
  tenant_id  bigint,
  invoice_id bigint,
  state      text,
  PRIMARY KEY (tenant_id, invoice_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id, invoice_id) REFERENCES tmp.invoice (tenant_id, invoice_id)
);

-- Generate a state for each tenant.
INSERT INTO tmp.invoice_state (tenant_id, invoice_id, state)
VALUES (0, 0, 'created'),
       (1, 1, 'draft'),
       (2, 2, 'draft'),
       (3, 3, 'finalized'),
       (4, 4, 'finalized'),
       (0, 5, 'created');

-- Show the states.
SELECT tenant_id, invoice_id, state, total_cents
FROM tmp.invoice
  JOIN tmp.invoice_state USING (tenant_id, invoice_id);

-- +---------+----------+---------+-----------+
-- |tenant_id|invoice_id|state    |total_cents|
-- +---------+----------+---------+-----------+
-- |0        |0         |created  |0          |
-- |1        |1         |draft    |1          |
-- |2        |2         |draft    |2          |
-- |3        |3         |finalized|3          |
-- |4        |4         |finalized|4          |
-- |0        |5         |created  |5          |
-- +---------+----------+---------+-----------+

-- Original table will become a partition to reduce data movement.
ALTER TABLE tmp.invoice
  RENAME TO invoice_pt0;

CREATE TABLE tmp.invoice (
  LIKE tmp.invoice_pt0 INCLUDING ALL
) PARTITION BY RANGE (tenant_id);

CREATE TABLE tmp.invoice_pt2 PARTITION OF tmp.invoice FOR VALUES FROM (2) TO (4);
CREATE TABLE tmp.invoice_pt4 PARTITION OF tmp.invoice FOR VALUES FROM (4) TO (MAXVALUE);

-- Violates foreign key constraints because tmp.invoice_state references
-- the original tmp.invoice, renamed to tmp.invoice_pt0.
--
-- ERROR: update or delete on table "invoice_pt0" violates foreign
--        key constraint "invoice_state_tenant_id_invoice_id_fkey"
--        on table "invoice_state"
--
-- Detail: Key (tenant_id, invoice_id)=(2, 2) is still referenced
--         from table "invoice_state".
WITH
  del AS (
    DELETE FROM tmp.invoice_pt0
    WHERE 2 <= tenant_id AND tenant_id < 4
    RETURNING *
  )
INSERT INTO tmp.invoice (tenant_id, invoice_id, total_cents)
SELECT * FROM del;
```

#### References

- [Postgres dynamically update constraint foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816116): Programatically alter foreign keys.
- [PgPartman native partition guide](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman/blob/master/doc/pg_partman_howto_native.md): Seems like PgPartman could automate most of the tediousness. Notes that accepting downtime is unavoidable.

> Taking the partitioned table offline is the only method that realistically works when you have foreign keys TO the table being partitioned

- [How to partition existing table in postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106014/how-to-partition-existing-table-in-postgres): trigger-based partitioning, doesn't handle foreign keys.
- [Add partitioning to unpartitioned table with minimal downtime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299025/add-partitioning-to-unpartitioned-table-with-minimal-downtime): For SQL server, recommends using a view. Doesn't handle foreign keys.
- [Efficiently attach a partition to a table with a foreign key to a partitioned table in PostgreSQL on Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74072727): has the reverse problem, foreign keys point from the table being partitioned to another table.
- [Partitioning in PostgreSQL when partitioned table is referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834510/partitioning-in-postgresql-when-partitioned-table-is-referenced?rq=4): predates declarative partitioning, answers hint at indexes and foreign-key workarounds.

Comment: That sounds about right. If you want to do without the down time, you can use logical replication (from v13 on).